# How to use a tensorflow dataset using a csv with a pth to each numpy file

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tensor

I own a dataset of numpy files and they are listed in a csv (path to each numpy file) with all my labels.
The feature column is the path to each file.

Reading some older question ([Effective way to read images from a csv file and return a tf.data.Dataset object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905939/effective-way-to-read-images-from-a-csv-file-and-return-a-tf-data-dataset-object#new-answer)), I though I could use something like this :

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
  image = np.load(path)
  return preprocess_image(image)

def load_and_preprocess_from_path_label(path, label):
  return load_and_preprocess_image(path), label

dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_features.values, train_labels.values))

dataset_train_Batched = dataset_train.map(partial(load_and_preprocess_from_path_label))
```

But I get an error because "path" is not a string nor a path but a tensor... How to read this tensor to get the value ?
I tried using

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
   sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
   with sess.as_default():
      a_value = sess.run(path)
   image = np.load(a_value)
   return preprocess_image(image)
```

It does not help.
I am stucked.

Could you help me to find how to read the path to preprocess my numpyfiles ?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

the issue is due to the "map" method.

You can use .numpy to get the value of a tensor but not using map.

For example :
This code works :

```
for ds,ds2 in dataset_train.take(1):
 pathtest, labeltest = load_and_preprocess_from_path_label(ds.numpy()[0], ds2)
```

But this one does not work :

```
dataset_train_Batched = dataset_train.shuffle(42).map(lambda x,y : load_and_preprocess_from_path_label(x.numpy[0],y)).batch(BATCH)
```

If you use the map method you have to use tf.py_function to read the tensor.

In my case :

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
  [image,] = tf.py_function(np.load, [path], [tf.string])
  return preprocess_image(image)

def load_and_preprocess_from_path_label(path, label):
  return load_and_preprocess_image(path), label
```

Have a good day